# ERR_SPDY_PROTOCOL_ERROR on facebook and wikipedia

Tags: google-chrome

I use chrome browser. And I get `ERR_SPDY_PROTOCOL_ERROR` really often, but on wikipedia and facebook only.

If this happens, I have to navigate to: `chrome://net-internals/#events&q=type:SPDY_SESSION%20is:active` and `flush sockets`

But it happens really often. How is it possible to permanently fix it?

Comment: Why the downvote? The `Web Applications` site users told me, to ask it here

Comment: are you using any antivirus software?

Comment: yes, avast. But after I've disabled it's browser plugin, I still get the error

Comment: try to add the websites, to which you’re getting the error to the Web Shield exclusions and test again if the error still resides

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SPDY is a protocol developed by Google in order to reduce web page load latency and to improve web security. Currently, the SPDY protocol is deprecated as the [HTTP/2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP/2) protocol has been ratified, so Google [announced](http://blog.chromium.org/2015/02/hello-http2-goodbye-spdy-http-is_9.html) they won't support SPDY anymore.

Although this issue has been repeatidly notified, it seems Google has not acknowledged this as a bug and there is not a permanent workaround to fix it.

However, there seems to be a relationship between this issue and using some antivirus/firewall software, especially Avast antivirus. Some users have reported to uninstall Avast and [not having issues](https://www.reddit.com/r/chrome/comments/3ej5ua/err_spdy_protocol_error/cv5pscn) since.

[Some others](https://www.reddit.com/r/chrome/comments/3j8ob4/help_spdy_protocol_error/) have reported to add a URL exclusion at the `Web Shield` of Avast and to get rid of the error as well.

To do so, you can follow this:

```
Settings > Active Protection > Customize Web Shield > Exclusions > Add https://facebook.com/*
```

Also, it seems to affect secure sites (`HTTPS`) more than insecure, as far as I could see.

Hopefully, if Google is not supporting SPDY anymore they will update their browser soon and users will get rid of it.

Answer (score 3):

There is lots of advice about how to deal with this problem.
I list below the advice I found, but you might need to go through all of them
in order to solve the problem.

1. Clear history/cookie/data
   This is done via menu access, or in the browser address bar:
   `chrome://settings/clearBrowserData` and use "From beginning of time".
   More info is [found here](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95582?hl=en-GB).
2. Clear host cache
   Type in browser address bar: `chrome://net-internals/#dns` and click
   "Clear Host Cache".
3. Close and flush sockets
   Type in browser address bar: `chrome://net-internals/#sockets` and
   click "Close Idle Sockets" and "Flush Socket Pools".
4. Clear DNS cache
   If you are using Windows, run as administrator the Command Prompt (cmd)
   and enter the commands : `ipconfig /flushdns` and `ipconfig /release`.
5. Run the Chrome Cleanup Tool
   If using Windows, run the [Chrome Cleanup Tool](https://www.google.com/chrome/cleanup-tool/).
6. Last is completely uninstalling Chrome, cleaning up all folders,
   then reinstalling the latest version.

If nothing helps, or the problem only stays fixed for a short time
and then returns again and again, you might consider using another browser.

Answer (score 1):

There are many working ways to fix these errors, You can any one and can fix very easily, 
Mostly it can fix by

1. Updating Google Chrome Browser
2. Flush the Socket Solution
3. Clear Cookies
4. Restart Browser

If still problem not solve then try manually for [more Chrome](https://www.howtoseeks.org/err_spdy_protocol_error/) fixes.

Answer (score 0):

There is no one single fix for this error. But you can try the ‘Clear Browsing Data’ method as it is mostly happening due to cookies.

1. Open browser and go to `settings`.
2. Now click on `Show Advanced Settings`.
3. Select `Clear Browsing Data`.
4. Restart your browser and done.

You can try more from this [tutorial](https://www.gizpc.com/err_spdy_protocol_error/) if the error is still showing.